# How to make button heights the same with different font sizes

Tags: html, css, font-size

I cannot make button heights same with different font sizes. I have to use em for height and width for responsive design.

Here is example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynxqjytz/3/)

CSS:

```
body{
  font-size:16px;
}
.btn{
  height:4em;
  font-size:1em;
}
.btn2{
  height:4em;
  font-size:1.50em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">First Button is 64px as expected</button>
<br><br>
<button class="btn2">Why this is not same height with first one?</button>

<p>
  How to make same height buttons with differnet font sizes ? 
</p>
```

Comment: try to give both of them same width

Comment: Yes. When you give same width it is working as expected. But why ? is this a bug ? Here is updated and it is working. both are have same width and working as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/ynxqjytz/4/

Comment: thats because you are using em which depends on font-size.

Comment: Yes. when you make same width now fonts are same too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that both `<button>` elements are different sizes is because you're defining the `height` in terms of the relative `em` unit of size, which is determined from the current `font-size`, and both `<button>` elements have different `font-size`.

While you say you "*have to use `em` for…responsive sizing* you can, instead, use the `rem` unit, which is the 'root-em' of the document, one `rem` will always be the same size regardless of the changed `font-size` of any descendant element.

For example:

```js
let button1 = document.querySelector('button.btn'),
  button2 = document.querySelector('button.btn2');

console.log(button1.clientHeight, button2.clientHeight);
// 60 60 (in my browser, yours will vary, but both
// buttons should show the same size).
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.btn2 {
  height: 4rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.50em;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">First Button is 32px as expected</button>
<br />
<br />
<button class="btn2">Why this is not same height with first one?</button>

<p>
  How to make same height buttons with differnet font sizes ?
</p>
```

Comment: The `line-height` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

`em`s are tied to font sizes, so when you change the font-size of `btn2` you are changing what `height: 4em` evaluates to. `rem`s will solve this problem for you **if you are able to use them**:

```css
body{
  font-size:16px;
}
.btn{
  height: 4rem;
  font-size:1em;
}
.btn2{
  font-size:1.50em;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">First Button is 64px as expected</button>
<br><br>
<button class="btn2">Why this is not same height with first one?</button>

<p>
  How to make same height buttons with differnet font sizes ? 
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I don't understand why do you say "if you are able to use them ? I am not an offical front end developer.

Comment: @OğuzCanSertel He says that because `rem` is not supported in older IE versions

Comment: @OğuzCanSertel that's correct. Check [caniuse: rems](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting ems for the font, and ems for the height.  An 'em' is equivalent to the current font size.  It's set by your initial body CSS to 16px, so 1em = 16px, which * 4 for the height of btn is 64px.  When you change the font size in btn2, you are adjusting the value of the em for that object as a whole, so your height of 4 em is now 1.5 * 16px * 4 = 96px.

Unless you are able to set the button's em value separately from the font size em I don't think you will succeed without manually reducing the 4em to something smaller so the math would work out on btn2.  If you're looking to keep that a consistent 4em then I'd suggest nesting elements somehow so you can set the values on separate elements.